# Using native hindi characters in a web site's source

Tags: web, hindi

I have made a sample webpage in hindi. The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>  

<body>
&#2361;&#2367;&#2344;&#2381;&#2342;&#2367;&#2350;&#2375;&#2348;&#2342;&#2354;&#2344;&#2366;
</body>
</html>
```

But I want the source code to appear in hindi as well (just like the BBC hindi website) and not in unicode. I mean ह instead of `&#2361;`
How can I do this?

Comment: Which tools did you use to create this page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Devanagari characters in your HTML source by not using HTML entities when creating the file. The following lines are equivalent.

```
<p>अ आ इ ई</p>
<p>&#2309; &#2310; &#2311; &#2312;</p>
```

If you are generating your HTML from a database, you might be applying an HTML entity conversion function at the time of generating the markup (such as `htmlentities()` in PHP). You'll have to remove that function call or apply it selectively.

Comment: That is what i want to know. How can i use devnagri characters in HTML source?

Comment: How are you generating this page? Is it through an editor like Dreamweaver or is it generated dynamically through a server-side programming language?

Comment: Paste your text in Code view. That should keep DW from converting the text into HTML entities. Beware that you might accidentally paste characters that cannot be displayed without conversion (such as ampersand). You'll also have to put in any tags by hand.

Comment: When i paste the text in code view, it appears as a sequence of rectangles. And the output is a sequence of question marks.

Comment: Your editor probably doesn't support Unicode then. Move to another one such as Sublime Text. That's what I used to type the code snippet pasted above.

Comment: I tried it in sublime. The output I'm getting is à¤¹à¤¿à¤¨à¥�à¤¦à¤¿

Comment: I tried it in notepad++ and it works for me. Thanks a lot for the help!